# Merge rows where 'PRODUCT_CODE' is

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to combine 2 data frames in pandas where if the column `PRODUCT_CODE` has similar row values, it should merge both rows without dropping value of other data columns. So far this is what I have tried below but my desired output is:

| PRODUCT_CODE | SERIAL_CODE | BATCH_ID | TL_CODE | TL_EXPIRY | PCE_STATUS | PCE_SN_STATUS | PCE_EXPIRY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC001 | SC001 | B001 | T001 | 2023-10-01 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| PC002 | SC002 | B002 | T002 | 2023-10-02 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| PC004 | SC004 | B004 | T003 | 2023-10-03 | Active | Valid | NaN |
| PC005 | SC005 | B005 | NaN | NaN | Inactive |  | Invalid |
| PC006 | SC006 | B006 | NaN | NaN | Active | Valid | 2024-10-03 |

I tried below:

```
desired_order = ['PRODUCT_CODE', 'SERIAL_CODE', 'BATCH_ID', 'TL_CODE', 'TL_EXPIRY', 'PCE_STATUS', 'PCE_SN_STATUS', 'PCE_EXPIRY']
# Create two sample DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'PRODUCT_CODE': ['PC001', 'PC002', 'PC004'],
                   'SERIAL_CODE': ['SC001', 'SC002', ''],
                   'BATCH_ID': ['B001', 'B002', ''],
                   'TL_CODE': ['T001', 'T002', 'T003'],
                   'TL_EXPIRY': ['2023-10-01', '2023-10-02', '2023-10-03']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'PRODUCT_CODE': ['PC004', 'PC005', 'PC006'],
                   'SERIAL_CODE': ['SC004', 'SC005', 'SC006'],
                   'BATCH_ID': ['B004', 'B005', 'B006'],
                   'PCE_STATUS': ['Active', 'Inactive', 'Active'],
                   'PCE_SN_STATUS': ['Valid', 'Invalid', 'Valid'],
                   'PCE_EXPIRY': ['2024-10-01', '2024-10-02', '2024-10-03']})
```

```
import pandas as pd

def combine_and_rearrange_dataframes(df1, df2, desired_order):
    # Concatenate the DataFrames
    combined_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

    # Identify unique columns using `.union`
    unique_columns = combined_df.columns.union(df1.columns)

    # Rearrange unique columns in the desired order
    final_df = combined_df[desired_order]

    # Update rows based on matching PRODUCT_CODES
    matching_product_codes = final_df['PRODUCT_CODE'].unique()
    for product_code in matching_product_codes:
        df_subset = final_df[final_df['PRODUCT_CODE'] == product_code]
        df_subset_updated = df1[df1['PRODUCT_CODE'] == product_code]
        final_df.update(df_subset_updated)

    return final_df

desired_order = ['PRODUCT_CODE', 'SERIAL_CODE', 'BATCH_ID', 'TL_CODE', 'TL_EXPIRY', 'PCE_STATUS', 'PCE_SN_STATUS', 'PCE_EXPIRY']
combine_and_rearrange_dataframes(df1, df2, desired_order)
```

Above function gives me below output:

| PRODUCT_CODE | SERIAL_CODE | BATCH_ID | TL_CODE | TL_EXPIRY | PCE_STATUS | PCE_SN_STATUS | PCE_EXPIRY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC001 | SC001 | B001 | T001 | 2023-10-01 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| PC002 | SC002 | B002 | T002 | 2023-10-02 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| PC004 |  |  | T003 | 2023-10-03 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| PC004 | SC004 | B004 | NaN | NaN | Active | Valid |  |
| PC005 | SC005 | B005 | NaN | NaN | Inactive |  | Invalid |
| PC006 | SC006 | B006 | NaN | NaN | Active | Valid | 2024-10-03 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` and keep the last non-null value like this:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).groupby('PRODUCT_CODE').apply(lambda df: df.replace("", None).ffill().iloc[-1])
```

It works like this:

1. `concat` will make a full dataframe with all rows and columns (columns which do not exist in other dataframe will be `NaN`)
2. `groupby` will select rows with the same `PRODUCT_CODE` into `df`
3. `ffill` propagates the last non-NaN value to the last row in this `df` (this is why "" to None replace is necessary)
4. the last rows of all groupbys are then returned

Answer (score 0):

You could [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and get the non-NaNs with [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.first.html):

```
cols = ['PRODUCT_CODE']

out = (pd.concat([d.replace('', float('nan')) for d in [df1, df2]])
         .groupby(cols, as_index=False).first()[desired_order]
       )
```

Output:

```
  PRODUCT_CODE SERIAL_CODE BATCH_ID TL_CODE   TL_EXPIRY PCE_STATUS PCE_SN_STATUS  PCE_EXPIRY
0        PC001       SC001     B001    T001  2023-10-01       None          None        None
1        PC002       SC002     B002    T002  2023-10-02       None          None        None
2        PC004       SC004     B004    T003  2023-10-03     Active         Valid  2024-10-01
3        PC005       SC005     B005    None        None   Inactive       Invalid  2024-10-02
4        PC006       SC006     B006    None        None     Active         Valid  2024-10-03
```